# Angular: update a behaviorsubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I was watching an angular university course on RxJs. One section described using behavior subjects to load data in a store service.

I tried to implement it in my angular app by creating the store service and initializing it when the app starts up (my AppComponent):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StoreService {

  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  private assetStatusSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IAssetStatusModel[]>([]);
  assetStatuses$: Observable<IAssetStatusModel[]> = this.assetStatusSubject.asObservable();

  init() {
    this.appService.getAssetStatuses().subscribe(
      (assetStatuses) => this.assetStatusSubject.next(assetStatuses)
    );

  }

  getAssetStatues() {
    return this.assetStatuses$;
  }

  refreshAssetStatuses () {
    this.appService.getAssetStatuses().subscribe(
      (assetStatuses) => {

        this.assetStatusSubject.next(assetStatuses);
        console.log('assetStatuses',this.assetStatuses$)
      }
    );
```

}

The whole point of this is that this data, which rarely changes, is used in a couple of places in the app. Setting it up this way will avoid having to make multiple API calls every time some component is loaded.

On the AppComponent, I call the store service init() function to initially populate the observable:

```
this.storeService.init();
```

On a component (component A) where I am using the assetStatuses$ observable (in a dropdown list), I got the data using:

```
this.assetStatuses$ = this.storeService.getAssetStatues();
```

and bind it to my dropdown. This is all working perfectly.

When I add a new status from the status component (component B), I call the refresh function in the store service from the component:

```
this.storeService.refreshAssetStatuses();
```

This seems to update the assetStatuses$ observable in the store because I can console it out and the newly added value is there. However, when I navigate away from component A (the one using the observable in the drop-down) and come back to it, it retains the old values even though I am calling the store service in the ngOnInit: this.storeService.getAssetStatues();

I don't know why this is returning the old values. If I do a hard fresh in the browser, they show up

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

One more thing I noticed. In my store service, the two functions I have, one for updating the observable and the other to get observable, return different values. If I call the refresh function first, after adding a new asset status, the console shows it updated the assetStatuses$ observable:

```
  refreshAssetStatuses(): void {
    this.appService.getAssetStatuses().subscribe(
      (assetStatuses) => {
        this.assetStatusesSubject.next(assetStatuses);
        console.log('assetStatuses',this.assetStatuses$) // this has the new value
      }
    );
  }
```

After that, when I call the function (in the same service) that gets the observable, the console doesn't show the new value:

```
getAssetStatuses() {
    console.log('getAssetStatuses',this.assetStatuses$); // the new value is missing
    return this.assetStatuses$;
  }
```

I don't get how that can happen since they are both referring to the same observable in the store service and the refresh, which was called first, clearly shows the assetStatuses$ has been updated.

I am perplexed :(

EDIT 2:

One more thing I fogot to mention is the the two components are lazy loaded. I thought provideIn: 'root' (since Angular 6) was supposed to make a singleton instance of the service. I am looking into this to make sure my implementation is correct for this scenario

Comment: Instead of using a direct reference to the observable in your component, try subscribing to it instead.

Comment: I also tried that: this.storeService.assetStatuses$.subscribe((data) => { console.log('data', 
 data)});
but the data varibale is still the old data.

Comment: Are you sure that component A is actually destroyed? Try adding a console.log/debugger in ngOnDestroy and check that it is actually destroyed.

Comment: Lars: I edited my post to show that the function in the store service that updates the observable has the new value. But when I call the function (in the same servcie) that returns the observable, it doesn't have the new value. See my edit in the post.

Comment: Ensure your StoreService is provided in only one providers array, or it will create a new instance for each component.

Comment: Schwarz54 - Thanks. In isn't in the provider array of any component. I am using provideIn: root in the service which is supposed to load a singleton instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of my found the issue. I had two browser tabs open when trying to test this. One tab was component A and the other component B. Behavior subjects are specific to a tab, they won't be updated in other tabs or other browser windows. I thought at least they would be shared across browser tabs. Valuable information to know.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is to make sure the reference to the store service is public in AppComponent, component A and component B.

You're also pushing to `this.businessUnitsSubject` but the observable is based on `this.assetStatusSubject` pushing to `this.assetStatusSubject` might be what you're wanting to do.

Comment: I am using DI in all the components: constructor(private storeService: StoreService) { }

Comment: sorry, that was a copy/paste error. I have more than one observable I am trying to do this with.I will update the question.

Comment: yeah, so you can use Dependency Injection but if you have it labeled as private it is injecting a different instance for each component. Making them public makes it so that each component references the same instance of the store service. So that should be constructor(public storeService: StoreService) { }. That's what I meant by the first part of my original response